# White edges on exported .pngs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, png

How do I get rid of the white edges on this exported .pngs? I have tried many different options (changing 8 bit to 16 bit, save for web, interlaced) and nothing seems to work. I also attached an image of what it looks like in Photoshop.

[image: png with white edges]

[image: in Photoshop]

Answer (score 9):

Its because of Matte.
Right now your Matte option is in white color
Make sure Matte - None
[image]